# Difference between RhoConnect and RhoSync

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes, rhoconnect

I am a newbie into cross mobile development, as i am from a Ruby background i choose Rhomobile Suite as it provides MVC architecture,i am very confused and want to know the differences b/w Rhoconnect and Rhosync, accordingly from the docs they are performing the same operations, but i would like to know the actual as many differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RhoConnect is the evolution of RhoSync.

Since 2013 [RhoSync is deprecated and no longer supported](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhosync).

Tho get more information about RhoMobile and RhoConnect can be found on [Tau-Technologies website](https://tau-technologies.com/). They currently maintaining these products and they provide enterprise support and training.